# Adding object to PFRelation through Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pfrelation

I am trying to add an object to a PFRelation in Cloud Code. I'm not too comfortable with JS but after a few hours, I've thrown in the towel.

```
                    var relation = user.relation("habits");
                    relation.add(newHabit);

                    user.save().then(function(success) {
                        response.success("success!");
                    });
```

I made sure that `user` and `habit` are valid objects so that isn't the issue. Also, since I am editing a `PFUser`, I am using the masterkey:

```
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw in the towel yet.  The likely cause is hinted at by the variable name `newHabit`.  If it's really new, that's the problem.  Objects being saved to relations have to have once been saved themselves.  They cannot be new.

So...

```
var user = // got the user somehow
var newHabit = // create the new habit
// save it, and use promises to keep the code organized
newHabit.save().then(function() {
    // newHabit is no longer new, so maybe that wasn't a great variable name
    var relation = user.relation("habits");
    relation.add(newHabit);

    return user.save();
}).then(function(success) {
    response.success(success);
}, function(error) {
    // you would have had a good hint if this line was here
    response.error(error);
});
```